# Writing content of two CDs into a DVD

Tags: dvd-burning

I have a movie, which is split in twice, because the source was 2 cd's. This movie has also subtitles(2 str files), which are synchronised.

I wish to put this movie, on a dvd and I don't know which tools to use, or which are the steps that I have to follow in order to accomplish my wish.

Can you give me some pointers?

Answer (score 1):

[DVD Flick](http://www.dvdflick.net/) is a DVD authoring tool and should let you add both video files to a single DVD.  It supports subtitles, is easy to use and it's free.

> **Features**
>
> - Burn near any video file to DVD
> - Support for over 45 file formats
> - Support for over 60 video codecs
> - Support for over 40 audio codecs
> - Easily add a menu
> - Add your own subtitles
> - Easy to use interface
> - Burn your project to disc after encoding
> - Completely free without any adware, spyware or limitations